# Print is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `div` that contains some `input` fields whose values are provided with jQuery.
Also I copied some code I found to print them, but when I press the button to print, the values from the fields are empty.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').val("Bruce");
        $('#lastname').val("Lee");
        $('#age').val("35");
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#printhem").click(function(){
           var divContents = $("#printedDiv").html();
           var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=900');

           printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>PRINTED</title>');
           printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
           printWindow.document.write(divContents);
           printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
           printWindow.document.close();
           printWindow.print();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="printedDiv"
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
    <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname">
    <input name="age" type="text" id="age">
    <div id="printhem">Print</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div id="printedDiv">`

Comment: `html()` method returns the html structure, but not the new values that you are writing. You need to set value after append.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude what do you mean? Any example?

Comment: The way your script create the printWindow content will show input fields, and not only their content, are you sure it is what you want (It will print the "Print" button too)? 

And not only print the values ?

Comment: After this statement: `printWindow.document.write(divContents);` you need to set the values of the inputs of the `divContents`. With `html()` method, you only copy the DOM structure, without values setting up in the document ready. If you render server-side the values html() will copy all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attr()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#name').attr('value',"Bruce");
$('#lastname').attr('value',"Lee");
$('#age').attr('value',"35");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omnk00n6/1/) check this may be it will helpful

```
<div id="printedDiv">
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
    <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname">
    <input name="age" type="text" id="age">

</div>
 <input type="button" value="Print Div Contents" id="prinThm" />


$("#prinThm").click(function(){
           var divContents = $("#name").val();
           var divContents2 = $("#lastname").val();
           var divContents3= $("#age").val();
           var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=900');

           printWindow.document.write('<html><head<title>PRINTED</title>');
           printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
             printWindow.document.write('<br/>');
           printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('<br/>');
           printWindow.document.write(divContents2);
           printWindow.document.write('<br/>');
           printWindow.document.write(divContents3);
           printWindow.document.write('<br/>');
           printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
           printWindow.document.close();
           printWindow.print();
        });
```